# Apply proguard to maven aar build

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I've build an aar using gradle on Android Studio.

The build itself went well, and i've managed to build the aar file.

I want to apply proguard to the pom file, and shrink my aar file size.

**I have a proguard file attached as proguardFiles to the buildTypes.**
When i open the aar file, i can see that the proguard file is there, but wasn't applied to the aar size.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), rootDir.absolutePath + '/proguard_debug.pro'
        }
   }
```

I've added this line when building the pom file, on my gradle :

```
pom.withXml { asNode().appendNode('build').appendNode('plugins').appendNode('plugin').
              appendNode('configuration').appendNode('proguard').with {
                    appendNode('skip', false)
              }
            }
```

This generates the entry in the pom file that was build :

```
<project>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <configuration>
              <proguard>
                <skip>false</skip>
              </proguard>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
</project>
```

But, here's my issue : **It doesn't look that the aar build was reduced in size.**

This is my reference : when i build the aar before the whole process of maven, the size of it was 2.7mb, and now its 5mb.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to enable ProGuard by adding the following:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true  // <- this will enabled ProGuard execution
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), ...
    }
}
```